# How to get data from model A in view B Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am quite new to Yii 2 and I am currently trying to display data from the `Teams` model in the `User` view in a `GridView`. In Yii1 I used a function with the `$data` variable. In Yii2 it does not seem to work that way.

I have tried the following in the `/user/index.php`

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Users');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="user-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create User'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>


    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            // ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            // 'iduser',
            'username',
            'surname',
            'givenname',
            'email:email',
            'mobile',
            'admin:boolean',
            'language',
            // Below is what I have been trying to do so far...
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\DataColumn',
             'label' => 'Teams',
             'value' => 'getTeams($data-teams)'
            ],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>


</div>

<?php
// And this is the function I use. In Yii1 it worked just fine.
function getTeams($data) {
    $tmp = "";foreach ($data as $team) {
      $tmp .=$team['name'].", ";
    }
    return trim($tmp, ", ");
  }
?>
```

**EDIT**

In the `User` model this is what I have set the relation as followed:

```
public function getTeamIdteams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Team::className(), ['idteam' => 'team_idteam'])->viaTable('user_has_team', ['user_iduser' => 'iduser']);
    }
```

While in the `Team` model I have set following relations:

```
public function getUserIdusers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['iduser' => 'user_iduser'])->viaTable('user_has_team', ['team_idteam' => 'idteam']);
    }
```

I have been looking around but can't seem to find a solution for this one. Basically I simply want the Team to be displayed in which the user is a part of. There is a table called `UserHasTeam` in which the id's of the teams and users are saved.

I am a little lost on how to go about the entire thing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have properly set relation to Team model in User model. See the [Relations via Junction Table](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#junction-table) part of guide if you don't know how to set the relation.

You can use closure in [`$value`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn#$value-detail) property of `DataColumn` to control what value is used for column.

```php
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        // ... other columns ...
        [
            'label' => 'Teams',
            'value' => function($model) {
                $tmp = "";
                foreach ($model->teams as $team) {
                    $tmp .= $team->name .", ";
                }
                return trim($tmp, ", ");
            }
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

You might also want to consider using [eager loading](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#lazy-eager-loading) to load all related at once instead of running query for each user in grid.

Comment: You can add a example of the relation what he supposed to have in his model to get it up voted. That will be help full anybody else. But i agree with you. you are right.

Comment: I have edited the question and show how the relations are set. There is a table in between these two tables called `User_Has_Team`. As said, I am really new to Yii2 and I might have messed up the relations.

Comment: Sometimes one just needs to open his eyes... The relation name is not `teams` but it it `teamIdteams`. Works perfectly.

Comment: Sry, I didn't have time to edit my reply to match your model. If you want to rename property where you find the teams from `$model->teamIdteams` to `$model->teams` you only need to rename the method defining relation from `getTeamIdteams` to `getTeams`.